# Calling vimgrep from a comand

Tags: vimgrep

I'm trying to create a command that would accept arguments, and then call `vimgrep` with those arguments and display the quickfix window. I set up my command like

```
command! -nargs=* Vsearch :call <SID>VimGrepSeach(<q-args>)
```

and my `<SID>VimGrepSearch` is defined by:

```
function <SID>VimGrepSearch(query) 
    execute "normal! q:vimgrep /\\v" . a:query . '\g' escape('**/*', ' \')
endfunction
```

This will search all of the current directory and display the results in a quickfix window, if the equivalent is ran directly from command mode.

However, when I run this as a command, I get the quickfix quickly popping up, but then it's immediately hidden. What's going on here? Why does the quickfix window appear and then hide, and how can I have it stay open?

Comment: Why are you using `q:`? That opens the command window. Try just `execute "vimgrep /\\v" ...` and then `copen` on the line below.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that gives me a "can't have multi follow a multi" because it's complaining about the path expansion `**/*`.

Comment: To be clear, I’m saying don’t change anything except to remove the `normal! q:`... that shouldnt give you any new errors

Comment: Actually, i think `\g` should be `/g`

Comment: Yeah putting it all together: `execute 'vimgrep /\v' . a:query . '/g **/*'` followed by `copen`. @D.BenKnoble, you got all of those, you should turn them into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function should just be

```
execute 'vimgrep /\v' . a:query . '/g **/*'
copen
```

Or you could do this with the command:

```
command -nargs=* Vsearch vimgrep /\v<args>/g **/* | copen
```